# Snowflake Scripting - using parameters in SQL select top n statement

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
create procedure my_proc(num int)
returns varchar
language SQL
execute as caller
as
$$

create table tbl1 as
select top :num * 
from db.schema.tbl
order by col1 desc;


$$;
```

getting a SQL compilation error:

> syntax error at line 2 unexpected select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TOP n` or `LIMIT n` require constant and not a variable.

> [`TOP <n>`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/top_n)
>
> - n must be a non-negative integer **constant**.

---

Alternative form that would allow parameters:

```
create table tbl1 as
select * 
from tab
qualify ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1 DESC) <= :num;
```

---

Otherwise dynamic SQL is required:

```
BEGIN
  LET sql := 
  'create or replace table tbl1 as
  select top <num> * 
  from tab
  order by col1 desc;';

  sql := REPLACE(sql, '<num>', num);

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(sql);
END;
```

This approach could lead to SQL Injection if arbitrary text input is allowed.