# Variable Substitution not working for Top N query in Snowflake

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

From the following two create procedure code, first one is working, but second one is throwing error: `Syntax error: unexpected 'id'. (line 14)` 
The only difference is the variable substitution of `TopN` parameter. How to fix this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testtop (
    TopN int,
    ChangeTypeId tinyint
)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
BEGIN
    TopN := COALESCE(TopN, 1000000000);
    ChangeTypeId := COALESCE(ChangeTypeId, NULL);

    select top 100 id,val from test t;

    return TopN;
    EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHER THEN
                RETURN 'OTHER_ERROR:'||SQLSTATE||':'||SQLCODE||':'||SQLERRM;
    END
;
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testtop (
    TopN int,
    ChangeTypeId tinyint
)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
BEGIN
    TopN := COALESCE(TopN, 1000000000);
    ChangeTypeId := COALESCE(ChangeTypeId, NULL);

    select top TopN id,val from test t;

    return TopN;
    EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHER THEN
                RETURN 'OTHER_ERROR:'||SQLSTATE||':'||SQLCODE||':'||SQLERRM;
    END
;
```

Comment: [Snowflake Scripting - using parameters in SQL select top n statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76663171/snowflake-scripting-using-parameters-in-sql-select-top-n-statement/76663236#76663236)

Comment: (voting to close this question, so it will show as a duplicate of @LukaszSzozda's above)