# Using variable size in limit clause in snowflake sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I want to limit number of rows using variable size where I get using CTE in snowflake: As a super easy example consider the following:

```
with num_groups as 
( select count(*) as num_group from table1 ) 

select
* from num_groups limit num_groups.num_group;
```

However something like this would work:

```
with num_groups as 
( select count(*) as num_group from table1 ) 

select
* from num_groups limit 10;
```

Is there any way to make the first query to work since I need to get the number of rows I want dynamically from another table.

Comment: you could use SQL scripting, to run the first query and then generate the second, and execute that, and return those results.

Comment: Why not use a $variable to store row count and later use it in the limit clause?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use the result of a CTE in the **LIMIT** clause of the main query. Other way you can achieve this is by using a stored procedure like this;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dynamic_limit()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
   var sql_command = "SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT " + RESULT_SET_COUNT();
   var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql_command});
   var result_set = stmt.execute();
   return result_set.toString();
$$;

CALL dynamic_limit();
```

Or, a scripting block like @Simeon said;

```
DECLARE
   num_groups INTEGER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :num_groups FROM table1;
   SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT ' || :num_groups;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :sql;
END;
```

Comment: I find your dynamic sql does not run, and the SET needs to be changed to `let sql text := 'SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT ' || :num_groups;` at which point the sql "works" and I can see in the history the limit query works, but the results are not returned from the anonymous block.

Answer (score 0):

### setup:

```
create database test;
create schema test.test;
use test.test;

create table table1 as (
    select value
    from table(flatten(ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(1, 6)))
);

create table table2 as (
    select value
    from table(flatten(ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(10, 20)))
);
```

### manual checks:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM test.test.table1;
```

[image]

```
select * from test.test.table2 
limit 5;
```

[image]

### dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE
  res RESULTSET;
  row_count INTEGER;
  select_statement VARCHAR;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO :row_count FROM test.test.table1;  
  
  select_statement := 'SELECT * FROM test.test.table2 limit ' || row_count;
  res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :select_statement);
  RETURN TABLE(res);
END;
```

gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `LIMIT` or `TOP` requires a **constant** and not an expression.

Workaround - using `QUALIFY`:

```
with num_groups as ( 
    select count(*) as num_group 
    from table1 
) 
select * 
from table 
qualify ROW_NUMBER() OVER() <= (SELECT num_group FROM num_groups);
```

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76663236/5070879

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to achieve this using Snowflake's [SQL variables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables). This is a 2-pass approach that doesn't require a stored procedure, query strings, or an expensive `QUALIFY` statement.

```
-- Calculate the size of our table and set it to a variable
SET tbl_count = (SELECT count(*) AS num_group FROM table1);

-- Use the tbl_count variable in the limit statement
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table2
LIMIT
  $tbl_count;
```